# True or false? An expectation inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value, integral-inequality

Is the inequality
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ |X| \right] \leq 1 + \mathbb{E}(X^2)
$$
True or false? I have been stuck trying to prove it with Jensen's inequality, in particular by noting that

$$
|\mathbb{E}[X]| \leq \mathbb{E}[|X|]
$$
However, I'm missing how to put the pieces together. Hope that somebody can help! :)

Comment: Maybe the relation $x^2 + 1 - 2 |x| \geq 0$ may help

Comment: A thought: $X^2=|X|^2$, so the inequality of interest may be written as $\mathbb{E}[|X|-|X|^2]=\mathbb{E}[|X|(1-|X|)]\leq 1$. But $|X|(1-|X|)\leq 1/4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality is true and is strict, and you can find it using the linear property of expectation by completing the square and then reversing the argument

- $0 \le \mathbb E\left[\left(\frac12-|X|\right)^2\right]$
- $0 \le \mathbb E\left[\frac14\right] -\mathbb E\left[|X|\right] + \mathbb E\left[|X|^2\right]$
- $\mathbb E\left[|X|\right] \le \frac14 + \mathbb E\left[X^2\right]  $
- $\mathbb E\left[|X|\right] \lt 1 +  \mathbb E\left[X^2\right]$

Comment: Nice, this inequality is basically AM-GM for two terms since (supposing $X\geq0$) $$X^2+\frac14\geq2\cdot\sqrt{\frac{X^2}{4}}=X.$$ Equality occurs iff $X\equiv\frac12$ almost everywhere

Answer (score 2):

It's true, as Henry showed. An alternate proof:
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb E[|X|] &= \mathbb E \left[ |X| \cdot 1_{|X|\leq 1} + |X| \cdot 1_{|X| > 1}\right] \\
&<\mathbb E \left[1 + |X|^2  \right]
\end{align*}
since $|X| \leq 1$ on the event $\{|X| \leq 1\}$ tautologically, and $|X|^2 > |X|$ on the event $\{|X| > 1\}$.

(I suppose the strict inequality is a tad more obnoxious to show in the case where $\{|X| > 1\} = \emptyset$, but it's not hard to see that it should hold there too.)